# How can I exclude resource files from being included in .war?

Tags: gradle

I have a small Spring/Gradle Liberty web service that is to be deployed to multiple environments.  I'd like to keep all the environment-specific resources out of the .war that contains the service.  The project structure is:

```
src/main/java/
src/main/resources
    ...resources used in all environments
resources/
    resources_deployment1
        ...resources used for deployment1
    resources_deployment2
        ...resources used for deployment2
    ...
...
```

I have tried putting the following in my build.gradle:

```
war {
    rootSpec.exclude( "resources/**" )
}
```

but when I look into the .war that gets deployed, I still see files
that come from `resources/resources_deployment1`.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
war {
    rootSpec.exclude("**/resources/**")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/resources/**")
}
```

Hope this worked!
You can refer [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-exlude-files-from-war-when-using-war-plugin-against-default-or-webappdirname-location/7366/10)

Comment: Alas, no, the files in `resources/resources_deployment1` still show up in the .war, in `WEB-INF/classes/`

Comment: did you try with "\*\*/src/main/resources/\*\*"

Comment: No, because I *do* want the resources there (which are deployment-independent) to be included in the .war   What I want to exclude is the deployment-specific resources in `resources/*`.

Comment: so all the deployment dependent and independent class files are present inside your /src/main/resources/ directory ? you want to exclude only files with _deployment in its name?

Comment: Nope:   /src/main/resources holds the deployment-independent resources.   The folders resources/<deployment>/ hold the deployment-dependent resources for each of the <deployment>s.

Comment: did u resolve it ? I am not able to exclude them using rootSpec.exclude '**/exclude*.jar'

Comment: did you try with '**/exclude.jar' ?